# (Python) Prime Number Function infinite loop

Tags: python, infinite-loop, primes

I'm currently working on a supercomputer to distribute a task (find prime numbers) to other machines. Right now I'm hitting an infinite loop somewhere, and I think I've tracked it down to my prime number function, but can't figure exactly where it is.
I'm only in into to compsci, so any help is greatly appreciated.

LB is the lower bound, UB upper bound of the range I want prime numbers from.

Thanks!

```
def do_work(self,LB,UB):

    msg = M_DATA
    initialdata = self.recv()
    n = UB
    p = 2
    total = 0


    for p in range(LB,UB):
        prime = True
        for i in range(2, p):
            if p % i == 0:
                prime = False
                break
        if prime == True:
            #print numbers found
            #print (p)
            total += 1

    return (total)
```

Comment: Where exactly you think is infinite loop? Debug the code and paste only relevant code.

Comment: as you have only used for..in range i dont see how this could ever get into an infinite loop, due to its nature some number would take a very long time to return from this function but it should always return.

Comment: You're programming a supercomputer in Python? And you don't know how to sieve for primes? How big do you expect LB and UB to be?

Comment: Your algorithm is just very ineffective, that’s why it’s taking so long. Please look on SO (or Wikipedia) for other prime number algorithms. There should be enough simple examples around.

Answer (score 0):

The distance between two primes increases and "tends towards infinity". Hence for quite big `LB`, the number of iterations necessary to find primes gets big enough to look like you're stuck in an infinite loop. That's why primes are hard to find.

You can improve your algorithm without much changes by looking at the definition of prime numbers. You don't need to check for the remainder of *each* integer less than `prime`, but only the primes lower or equal than `sqrt(prime)` to give a definitive answer. Take 2 for instance: if a number isn't divided by 2, it won't be devided by an even number (4, 6, 8, 10, etc.).

You can then halve the number of iterations necessary by using `range(UB, LB, 2)` in your outer loop, given that UB is odd (that is `range(UB + (1 - (UB % 2), LB, 2)`).

For your inner loop, store a list of found primes and iterate over it while the it's lower than `sqrt(prime_to_check)`. That'll help a lot.

Comment: BTW, I'm not saying that's the *best* algorithm to find primes, just a better one ;—)

Comment: ... lower *or equal*, yes? on a supercomputer, with the abundance of cores, data independence might outweigh the minor complexity improvement of working with primes only a.o.t. all (odd) numbers; what's ***imperative*** is the `sqrt` limit.

Comment: Yes, that is lower or equal. But I don't thinks that iterating over primes only in the inner loop is a *minor* improvement, especially for big primes. WolframAlpha reports 1229 primes lower than 10000. That is a reduction of 76% in the number of iterations over just checking odd numbers for primes between 10⁹ and 10⁹+140049. It only gets better with bigger bounds. You can save over 89% iterations between 10¹⁶ and 10¹⁶+14⋅10⁸. That's because the prime density for numbers lower than `n` is about `1/ln(n)`.

Comment: `log n` is minor compared with the `sqrt(n)`. To test by primes you'd have to maintain some source for them, and take them from there, leading to all sorts of synchronization issues - but testing by odds you can just generate the odds on the spot. so for parallel code on many CPUs the advantage of testing by primes is not so obvious.

Comment: I agree that the relative gain from testing over `[2 .. prime]` to `[2 .. sqrt(prime)]` far outweighs the latter optimization (from `[2 .. sqrt(prime)]` to `primes in [2 .. sqrt(prime)]`). Just [look at the curves](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+x%2C+sqrt%28x%29%2C+sqrt%28x%29%2Flog%28x%29+from+1+to+10000000). (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) My point is, prime computation is *very* expensive, operation-wise, and every bit of optimization helps a lot in the long run. Also, one probably stores the primes somewhere anyways, and querying a Redis to retreive those isn't much work. For parallelization, just make sure to store the last checked integer, and fallback to even numbers if you don't have all the primes up to `sqrt(p)`. But of course, depending on your stack and implementation, this can prove difficult. I'm just trying to give a complete answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tested the function? See below, for an example function extracted from your method. Without going into its efficiency and all, it doesn't seem to have an infinite loop, though you can see it as per the logic as well.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

def do_work(LB,UB):
    p = 2
    total = 0
    primes = []

    for p in range(LB,UB):
        prime = True
        for i in range(2, p):
            if p % i == 0:
                prime = False
                break
        if prime == True:
            #print numbers found
            primes.append(p)
            total += 1

    return LB, UB, total, primes

for i in xrange(100): print do_work(2, i)
```

A couple of things to note: you have variables like msg, initialdata, n which are not being used. The return statement is somewhat strange. `return (total,)` would return a tuple containing total. `return total` would return just the total.

M_DATA and self.recv() are unknown here, so I venture that you might have an infinite loop related to those.